# Web application shared on Facebook Messenger. Can I make it to use Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, web, cross-browser

I'm developing a PWA, so it's supposed to be extremely mobile friendly. And it's a social app so the user has to share URLs a lot. But whenever a URL is shared on FB messenger, if we click on the URL, the messenger in app browser is used and the app doesn't work well (the user can't even refresh the app)... Is there a way I can force the URL to be used with another browser ?

Comment: On mobile devices the browser is usually defined by the app first. Apps will often have a setting whether to open links using an internal or external browser. I don't know if there's a way to circumvent that.